# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory - on linux, using absolute path

Tags: python, pytest

I am struggling to find the solution for this. I am using an absolute path that definitely exists in the file system. When same exact path is used in same script with

```
if host.file(logPath).exists:
    print("Exists: " + logPath)
```

I get

```
Exists: /var/opt/jws/jws3.0/v7/testinfra_node1/logs/catalina.out
```

But when trying:

```
with open(logPath, "rt") as log:
```

I am getting:

```
>               with open(logPath, "rt") as log:
E               IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/opt/jws/jws3.0/v7/testinfra_node1/logs/catalina.out'
```

Here is the whole code (it is a testinfra script for testing JWT installation):

```
import pytest
import testinfra
import time
import os

@pytest.mark.parametrize("jws_version", [("3.0")])

def test_server_recycle(host, jws_version):
    instances = host.check_output("cat /var/opt/jws/jws" + jws_version + "/init/init_instances | grep -oP '(\/.*?\/)((?:[^\/]|\\\\/)+?)(?:(?<!\\\\)\s|$)'")
last = ""
for last in iter(instances.splitlines()):
    pass
last = last.strip().encode('ascii','ignore')
print(last)

instanceName = ""
for instanceName in iter(last.split("/")):
    pass
print(instanceName)

binPath = last + "/bin/"
logDir = last + "/logs/"
logPath = os.path.join(logDir, "catalina.out")
print(logPath)

runningAt0 = isInstanceRunning(host, instanceName)
if host.file(logPath).exists:
    print("Exists: " + logPath)

if (runningAt0):
    with host.sudo():
        host.run(os.path.join(binPath, "shutdown.sh"))    
        with open(logPath, "rt") as log:
            result = waitForEntry(log, "INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService- Stopping service Catalina","ERROR")
        assert not result.eq("ERROR")
        assert not isInstanceRunning(host, instanceName)
        host.run(os.path.join(binPath, "/bin/startup.sh"))
        with open(logPath, "rt") as log:
            result = waitForEntry(log, "INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina- Server startup in","ERROR")
        assert not result.eq("ERROR")
        assert isInstanceRunning(host, instanceName)
else:
    with host.sudo():
        host.run(os.path.join(binPath, "startup.sh"))
        with open(logPath, "rt") as log:
            result = waitForEntry(log, "INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService- Stopping service Catalina","ERROR")
        assert not result.eq("ERROR")
        assert isInstanceRunning(host, instanceName)
        host.run(os.path.join(binPath, "shutdown.sh"))
        with open(logPath, "rt") as log:
            result = waitForEntry(log, "INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina- Server startup in","ERROR")
        assert not result.eq("ERROR")
        assert not isInstanceRunning(host, instanceName)

def isInstanceRunning(host, instanceName):
    processes = host.check_output("ps auwwx | grep catalina.startup.Bootstrap")
    if  "-Dtomcat.inst.name=" + instanceName in processes:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def waitForEntry(file, entry1, entry2):
    while 1:
        file.seek(0,2)
        line = file.readline()
        if entry1 in line:
            return entry1
        else:
            if entry2 in line:
                return entry2
            else:
                time.sleep(0.1)
```

Instead of

```
host.file(logPath).exists
```

I have been also trying

```
print(host.check_output("cat " + logPath))
```

and it prints the file contents nicely.

Any ideas on how to approach this?
Many thanks in advance!

Edit:
Here is how I execute the script:

> py.test -v --host=user@host tomcat_test_recycle.py --sudo

Comment: `host.file(logPath).exists` should be `host.file(logPath).exists()`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: I think not. This one is from testinfra module: https://testinfra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules.html#testinfra.modules.file.File.
This is what I get after your proposed modification:
>       if host.file(logPath).exists():
E       TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Comment: @Idlehands: Like I mentioned before, this .exists is an attribute, not a method. Also, the file definitely exists, as I am able to read it's contents within the same script, using the same path variable.

Comment: How come the code has `"rt"` as the open mode but the provided error message says `"rb"`?

Comment: @Arc676: I have copied it from the wrong test result. Was trying different options (rt, rb) - result was the same. I will now edit the question to fix this discrepancy. Thanks!

Comment: Is `host.file(logPath).exists` checking it exists **on a remote host**?

Comment: @donkopotamus: yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `testinfra` package appears to integrate testing the state of **remote** servers into `pytest`.  Thus

```
host.file(logPath).exists
```

and

```
host.check_output("cat " + logPath)
```

are checking the existence and the contents on a **remote** server, whereas

```
open(logPath, "rb")
```

is acting on the **local** machine.  The file is not on the local machine, it’s on `host`.

Comment: It struck me after your comment. Thank you very much!